# Is there an automatic way to deduplicate .gitignore rules?

Tags: git, web-services, gitignore, bittorrent-sync

Is there some tool or webservice that takes a .gitignore file, tests the rules somehow and notifies one about duplicate rules (i.e. whose matches overlap)?

I have a long-running Git-repository that was initialised with several of [GitHub's default .gitignore templates](https://github.com/github/gitignore), which were amended manually over the course of several months. After removing some obvious duplicate ignore rules such as `test-A.md` and `test-*` manually I started wondering.

So far, I found methods to clean a text of duplicate phrases, but nothing that could actively evaluate the ignore rules. An answer may be useful for [Syncthing](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing#syncthing) and BitTorrent Sync users trying to clean up convoluted .syncignore rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic tool available as per my knowledge. But you can make use of the [git-check-ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) for each rule through the command line.

Example:

```
git check-ignore -v filename
```

From the documentation

> For each pathname given via the command-line or from a file via
>   --stdin, check whether the file is excluded by .gitignore (or other input files to the exclude mechanism) and output the path if it is
>   excluded.
>
> By default, tracked files are not shown at all since they are not
>   subject to exclude rules; but see ‘--no-index’.

Answer (score 0):

you can use global .gitignore when you declare it in your .gitconfig as following.

```
[core]
   excludesfile = /Users/your_user_name/.gitignore_global
```